# QGIS Server is proxying online map services on Ubuntu 22.04 for dynamic projection conversion, but export is empty

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gis, qgis

We create a project in QGIS that loads an online TianDiTu`s WMTS service and performs coordinate transformation. Then we publish this project through QGIS server to obtain a dynamically projected map service.

The entire process works perfectly in a Windows environment, but in an Ubuntu environment, the published service always returns a blank.

Is there a difference in the capabilities of QGIS in Ubuntu and Windows environments?

for example:
http://192.168.8.111:8081/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?MAP=/home/qgis/dzdt3857.qgz&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

QGIS Server is working on Windows

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.